# Delete UITableViewCell using custom UIButton

Tags: iphone, uibutton, nsindexpath

I have encountered this error when trying to delete a cell, using a custom button.

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM removeObjectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

Heres how my code is structured. I have a custom `UITableViewCell` that contains a `UIButton` which has an action that deletes the cell. The action for deleting the cell is in my main View controller, that contains the actual `indexPath` for the cells. This structure works fine.

Heres the action to delete the cell.

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self globalIndexPath];

[self.array removeObjectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
[db deleteTaskAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath,nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

When I declare the `indexPath` above, the `globalIndexPath` property is set in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, giving it the value of the original `indexPath`. This is how I declared it.

```
[self setGlobalIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Now I have laid some `NSLogs` here an there to log the `indexPath`. For example in the `viewWillAppear` method and the `viewDidLoad` method, and both give me the accurate `indexPath`, and I even checked the `array` outputs and all of them return accurate results, so I really don't know why it's giving me the error.

Here is the code in my custom cell, to detect when the button is tapped.

```
NSArray *notificationArray = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];
if (!notificationArray || !notificationArray.count)
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"DeleteSignal" object:nil];
}
else
{
    UILocalNotification *notif = [notificationArray objectAtIndex:[checkbox tag]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notif];
}
```

And then I delete the the cell using the `NSNotificationCenter` with the key `DeleteSignal`.

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint when [indexPath row] is >= [self.array count] before each remove...or an assert that row is less than count.  Also, any chance you're deleting multiple items without refreshing the table?

Comment: I will try the breakpoint, but Yes, I have tried reloading my `tableView` in my `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: I did a if statement right before and after my delete functions, and put a log but i don't know exactly how that will work.

Comment: I was hoping that if you hit a breakpoint where your indexPath.row was beyond the end of the array it would be possible to see how things got out of synch.  (The logic for globalIndexPath maybe.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are setting the globalIndexPath in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` (and nowhere else), globalIndexpath will always know the indexPath for the last cell, which got created or dequeued, *not* the one where the user might actually use the button. Seems already broken by design. Or are your cells that large that only one is visible?

At first I would try setting the tag of your `UIButton` of your cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
myButton.tag = indexPath.row + SOMEOFFSETTOASSUREYOURTAGDOESNTGET0;
```

and then get the indexPath in your action via this tag:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(UIButton*)sender.tag - OFFSET inSection:0];
```

Of course that only works if you have just one section. If you need to handle multiple sections you could use an array which contains all your indexPaths and set the tag of your `UIButton` to the index of that indexPath in your array.

**UPDATE**

While it's technically possible to (mis)use `NSNotificationCenter` for what you are doing, I would really advise you to walk through this [tutorial](http://www.roostersoftstudios.com/2011/05/01/iphone-custom-button-within-a-uitableviewcell/).

Comment: my action is in the main view controller, and it's just a simple `void`. Your code for declaring the `indexPath` returns an error saying sender is undeclared. Is it supposed to be my button?

Comment: Did you define a protocol and use a delegate in your custom `UITableViewCell` to call that action?

Comment: And yes, sender should be your UIButton.

Comment: My action is not in my Custom cell class, it's in the class where I am getting the `indexPath` from, and I am posting the action to my Custom cell class using `NSNotificationCenter`, so if `sender` is equal to my button then how am I going to declare it?

Comment: No, I haven't declared a protocol or delegate in my Custom cell. I will update my code to show you my action for when the button is tapped.